# LSP (Layered Service Provider) OS compatibility

Tags: windows, winsock-lsp

Which operating systems support LSP (Layered Service Provider)?

Interesting operating systems (Windows XP 32/64bit,Windows Vista 32/64bit, Windows 7 32/64bit, Windows Server 2008 32/64bit, Windows Server 2008 R2 32/64bit)

Comment: Where in official documentation i can confirm LSP OS compatbility? Do i can with LSP change namespace traffic? What difference between LSP and WFP?

Answer (score 2):

Layered Service Providers will work on Windows 2000 and up.  For the 64 bit OSes you will have to provide a 32 and 64 bit version of your LSP and register them both.  LSPs do not interact with namespace traffic.  I believe that you can write a namespace provider for that purpose (but I have not done this myself).  LSPs are part of Winsock 2.  So any Winsock 2 compliant OS would support LSPs.  Check out the Winsock 2 docs on the MSDN library. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms740673(v=VS.85).aspx

If you are using Windows Vista or later then the Windows Filtering Platform WFP is the way to go.  It is a newer filtering technology built into the OS that replaces LSPs (and some other filtering methods in kernel mode).  You can do many things with the user mode WFP API that would have required an LSP (block sites, ports, applications). Be aware though that advanced uses of the WFP require you to write a kernel mode callout driver (where an LSP is strictly user mode).

Answer (score 1):

LSPs are not supported for "Modern" (Metro) apps in Windows 8. To monitor those apps, you have to write a WFP filter instead. IE11's "Enhanced Protected Mode" also does not support LSPs even in desktop mode.